# How to implement topic modelling in regression analysis

Tags: r, linear, text-mining, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I have a dataset consisting of hotel reviews, ratings, and other features such as traveller type, and word count of the review. I want to perform topic modeling (LDA) and use the topics derived from the reviews as well as other features to identify the feature that most affects the ratings (ratings as the dependent variable).

If I want to use linear regression to do this, does this mean I would have to label each review with the topics derived? Is there a way to do this in R or will I have to manually label each review?
(I am pretty new to text mining and data science in general.)

Answer (score 2):

Typically, no manual labelling is required. When using LDA (or another topic model) to build a classifier or other predictive model, a common workflow is to:

- Fit the unsupervised LDA model on the training data
- Transform the data using the fitted LDA model
- Train, validate, test etc. the supervised model using the transformed representations as features.

I couldn't speak to R, but scikit-learn's LDA implementation has a pretty intuitive [`transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html#sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.transform) method, and their [pipeline examples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#examples-using-sklearn-pipeline-pipeline) might give an idea how unsupervised and supervised methods can be chained together.